# Jquery split 1 variable become 2 variable

Tags: jquery

I have date time range data, I want to split this data became to 2 variable. The code like this :

```
var dtrange = "2014/11/05 12:00 AM - 2014/11/05 12:00 AM";
```

and I want the result like this:

```
var startdate = "2014/11/05 12:00";
var enddate   = "2014/11/05 12:00";
```

How to resolve this problem?
Please help me thank's before :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = dtrange.split(" - ");
var startDate = temp[0];
var enddate = temp[1]
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var dtrange = "2014/11/05 12:00 AM - 2014/11/05 12:00 AM";
var dates=dtrange.split('-');
var startdate =dates[0].trim();
var enddate   =dates[1].trim();
console.log(startdate);
console.log(enddate);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var splitStr = dtrange.split("-");
var startdate = $.trim(splitStr[0]);
var enddate = $.trim(splitStr[1]);
```